# Meteor get static data from a collection for search engine

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to index a Meteor website but all the data fetched by subscriptions do not render for search engine, even with the spiderable package. Is there a way to get data from the server mongoDB and to render it in a static way that it can be crawled by search engine?

Comment: The spiderable package is the way to go. If it doesn't work for you, it's probably you who have done something wrong. It's probably better to find out what you've done wrong than discussing alternative solutions (I know of none at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

```
   waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("dbName");
    }
```

try this in router, to wait subscription complete before render

or try `fastRender` package